# Prevent refreshing from DOM Form Submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, dom

I was wondering if it was possible to prevent the page from refreshing on submission with the code I have below:

```
var new_element         = document.createElement('input');
new_element.type        = 'hidden';
new_element.name        = 'save';
new_element.value       = '';

var form_element = document.getElementById('document_form');    

form_element.appendChild(new_element);

form_element.submit();
```

Comment: You need to use `AJAX` to prevent refreshing after submit.

Comment: I am currently using angularjs, is there any way with angular?

Comment: Use `ng-submit`. Typically no reason you should need to add a hidden input in an angular form if you aren't submitting the actual form

Comment: You can bind to submit event and use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default action of submit. All native javascript functions are available in angular.

Comment: @RaheelAnwar that is already done in `ng-submit`

Comment: yeah totally agreed! ng-submit handles default behaviour. Both approaches are good just depends personal preference. @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

The form submit action is a navigation event, if you don't want a page reload you have to not use the submit action.
Then you need to projcet another type of strategy, for example using ajax to send a request and obtain a response.

this is a jquery example:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  //data contains the response
});
```

or using AngularJS as you wrote in your comment:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

here details about agularjs $http object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http